# PDF Field Library

Tags: pdf, libraries

Are there any JavaScript libraries (or any language library really) who is able to take a PDF with open fields and fill them in with values?

## EDIT

Since this question seems to be garnering negative feedback, I'll clarify my needs a bit more.  I would like to be able to have a web form that allows users to upload a PDF.  After getting the PDF I would like to find the editable fields and input them with information in a database.

I'm primarily looking for a library to be able to read the fields in the PDF and alter them.  I've seen [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), however it isn't really all that free and support seems very iffy (read: expensive). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In regard to the down votes - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one had any idea of what to do, this is my solution (and probably the best solution if you are developing a node.js app).

[Use this library](https://github.com/countable/js-fdf) to write data from your database into .fdf format.  FDF files are a way of storing data in an Adobe-friendly format.

After that has been generated, you can merge together the FDF and PDF files into one single merged PDF using the [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) command line tool.

The syntax of PDFtk looks something like this:

```
pdftk example.pdf fill_form formatted-data.fdf output merged.pdf
```

After that's done, you can upload the changed .pdf.  You'e welcome, random person who reads this.  It took me a while to figure out so hopefully this post will save you time.